# Pycharm - Package installation on Windows

Tags: pandas, package, pycharm

I have successfully installed anaconda on Windows 7.
Pandas and numpy work fine with IPython notebook and I have verified that anaconda is referenced on the PATH.

Yet, I can not install the pandas package wothin Pycharm.
I am not sure how to proceed.

```
Install packages failed: Error occurred when installing package pandas. 

The following command was executed:

packaging_tool.py install --build-dir C:\Users\mferrini\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging5585301427553978431.tmp pandas

The error output of the command:


Downloading/unpacking pandas
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pandas
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'docs'
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'f2py.1'
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'
    Running from numpy source directory.
    c:\users\mferrini\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gartid\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1526: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\mferrini\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gartid\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1535: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\mferrini\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gartid\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1538: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\mferrini\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gartid\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1432: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\mferrini\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gartid\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1443: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\mferrini\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gartid\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1446: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\mferrini\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging5585301427553978431.tmp\pandas\setup.py", line 619, in <module>
        **setuptools_kwargs)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 239, in __init__
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 263, in fetch_build_eggs
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 568, in resolve
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 806, in best_match
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 818, in obtain
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_egg
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 609, in easy_install
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 639, in install_item
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 825, in install_eggs
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1031, in build_and_install
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1019, in run_setup
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'

non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'docs'

non-existing path in 'numpy\\f2py': 'f2py.1'

non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'

Running from numpy source directory.

c:\users\mferrini\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gartid\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1526: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\mferrini\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gartid\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1535: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\mferrini\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gartid\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1538: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\mferrini\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gartid\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1432: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\mferrini\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gartid\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1443: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting

    the LAPACK environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)

c:\users\mferrini\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-gartid\numpy-1.9.1\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1446: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting

    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

  warnings.warn(msg)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\mferrini\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging5585301427553978431.tmp\pandas\setup.py", line 619, in <module>

    **setuptools_kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 111, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 239, in __init__

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 263, in fetch_build_eggs

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 568, in resolve

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 806, in best_match

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 818, in obtain

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_egg

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 609, in easy_install

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 639, in install_item

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 825, in install_eggs

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1031, in build_and_install

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1019, in run_setup

distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\mferrini\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging5585301427553978431.tmp\pandas
Storing complete log in C:\Users\mferrini\pip\pip.log
```